# Back button doesn't refresh page if URL contains GET parameters or trailing slash?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome, firefox

I have a CodeIgniter site that assigns users a UUID when the landing page is hit. Reloading the landing page will assign a new UUID, but once you start progressing through the forms your UUID remains the same. However something is happening I don't quite understand when the user hits the back button, and the behavior is different depending on what URL they arrived with?

Case 1: `domain.com/somehash?key=value` OR `domain.com/somehash/`

If you arrive with the above url containing a GET parameter, submit the first form (which contains your uuid), and press the back button, you return to the landing page but your UUID does not change.

Case 2: `domain.com/somehash`

With no GET parameters, if you submit the first form (which contains your uuid) and press the back button, you return to the landing page and receive a NEW uuid.

I tested this in the latest Chrome and Firefox, is it linked to some kind of caching strategy they implement? Ideally hitting back would NOT refresh the page.

EDIT: I should note we can't use cookies for this tool, so sessions are out

Further edit: Simply going to `domain.com/`, adding a backslash, stops the UUID from refreshing when hitting the back button. Possibly related to CodeIgniter routes.php or .htaccess?

Relevant .htaccess entries:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['(:any)'] = 'home/index/$1';
```

Comment: Where are you assigning the UUID, php or JS?

Comment: PHP, generated in the Controller before it's passed to the View in CI.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting these headers and see if that makes the behavior consistent in both scenarios:

```
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
$this->output->set_header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

More info: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html

Comment: No change, having a GET parameter or trailing slash still does not force a refresh when hitting Back. Without a backslash/GET hitting back does force a refresh.

Comment: Strange. Could you update your question with the php you use to append the UUID to the URL?

Comment: actually the UUID is just a hidden form field, embedded when you hit the landing page, it doesn't appear in the URL.

Comment: It is definitely a caching issue. For whatever reason, CI is treating the URLs differently. Did you set the output header as the very last thing in your controller? Also, is case 1 or case 2 the outcome you want?

Comment: yes set the headers as the final thing in the controller, and verified via Chrome inspector those headers were received. The ideal outcome would be no refreshing of UUID when clicking back, only on a deliberate, hard refresh